# How to use method position() after method children()

Tags: jquery, position, children

I need to get the position attribute of an element **A** by using the method **position()**, but what I only know is **A** is a child of an `"a"` tag.
So I use `$("a").children().position()`.But failed since what the method **children()** return is a jQuery object. And I do this`$("a"),children()[0].position()` (I know the **A** is the first child of the`"a"`tag). But the exception goes like

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).children(...)[0].position is not a function

Please help, thx

Answer (score 0):

`$("a").children()` matches all children of all `a` tags.

`$("a").children()[0]` gets the first match, as a DOM element. Instead, use `.first()` which returns another jquery object.

`$("a").children().first().position()`